# How to assign links to arrays

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to assign links to each array so for each 'subject' in my code, I want Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 to have different links for different webpages.So when the submit button is pressed the user will be brought to the webpage. 
So for example the user will go to the webpage, click on subject, click on a question and when they click submit they'll be brought to the question page (.html or whatever).

```js
var subjects = new Array("English", "Irish", "Maths", "German", "History", "Business", "Geogrpahy");
var questions = new Array();
questions["English"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
questions["Irish"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
questions["Maths"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
questions["German"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
questions["History"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
questions["Business"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");
questions["Geogrpahy"] = new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");

function resetForm(theForm) {
  /* reset subjects */
  theForm.subjects.options[0] = new Option("Please select a subject", "");
  for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
    theForm.subjects.options[i + 1] = new Option(subjects[i], subjects[i]);
  }
  theForm.subjects.options[0].selected = true;
  /* reset questions */
  theForm.questions.options[0] = new Option("Please select a question", "");
  theForm.questions.options[0].selected = true;
}

function updateModels(theForm) {
  var make = theForm.subjects.options[theForm.subjects.options.selectedIndex].value;
  var newModels = questions[make];
  theForm.questions.options.length = 0;
  theForm.questions.options[0] = new Option("Please select a question", "");
  for (var i = 0; i < newModels.length; i++) {
    theForm.questions.options[i + 1] = new Option(newModels[i], newModels[i]);
  }
  theForm.questions.options[0].selected = true;
}

resetForm(document.autoSelectForm);
```

```html
<form name="autoSelectForm" action="" method="post">
  <select size="1" name="subjects" onchange="updateModels(this.form)">
  </select>
  <select size="1" name="questions" onclick="">
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your variables and data, it doesn't really make sense to rewrite this code `new Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4");` for each question, because it seems redundant to do it that way. This can be simplified to this way:

P.S. **pure javascript** is too handy for a beginner, use **jQuery** instead get  jquery from [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)

**HTML**

```
// we use target="_blank" and method="get" here just to show that it works
<form id="myform" name="autoSelectForm" action="http://example.com/something.php" method="get" target="_blank">
  <select size="1" name="subjects" id="subjects"></select>
  <select size="1" name="quarters" id="quarters"></select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var subjects = [
     {
        subject: "English", quarters: [
          {name: "Q1", link: "http://example.com/engQ1.html"}, 
          {name: "Q2", link: "http://example.com/engQ2.html"}
        ]
     },
    {
      subject: "Irish", quarters: [
        {name: "Q1", link: "http://example.com/irQ1.html"}, 
        {name: "Q2", link: "http://example.com/irQ2.html"}
      ]
    }
]

var s_subj = $('#subjects');
var s_quar = $('#quarters');

setDropdownOptions(subjects);
refreshQuarters();  // load the quarters for the first subject

    function setDropdownOptions(values){
       var str_subjects = '';
        $.each(subjects, function(i, row){
          str_subjects+= '<option>'+row.subject+'</option>'; 
        });
       s_subj.html(str_subjects);
    }

   function refreshQuarters(){
       var current_subj = s_subj.val();
        $.each(subjects, function(i, row){
             if(current_subj == subjects[i].subject){
                 var str_quarters = "";
                 // loop through the subject's quarters
                 $.each(row.quarters, function(col, obj){
                    // we use data-link in storing each individual urls
                    str_quarters += '<option data-link="'+obj.link+'">'+obj.name+'</option>';
                 });
                 s_quar.html(str_quarters);
             }
        });
   }

  // add listener when subject is changed
  s_subj.change(function(){
    refreshQuarters();
  });

  // change the form action before submitting the form
  $("#myform").submit(function(){
      // get the link from the selected quarter through data-link
      var link = $("#quarters option:selected").data("link");
     $(this).attr("action", link);
  });
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/hs3oLrns/1/

Comment: Hi dexter this has been the best answer so far. However you haven't explained how to give each question a different link. Here you've linked every option to the same link - example.com.

Comment: @AaronC About the different links for each question, let's say, you redirect the user to `results.php`, when you submit a form with a `GET` method you will see something like `results.php?subject=English&quarter=Q3` in the url which means it's a different link but is executed on the same file, so in your `results.php` you get the `subject` and `quarter` using `$_GET['subject']` and `$_GET['quarter']` from the `url`. So these will be the variables you'll have to use on fetching questions or whatever from your database.

Comment: I see where you're coming from but it isn't what I'm looking for. The question pages will have their own .php link. All i want is the Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 in each subject to have a href value of ... .html. This will make things a lot easier for me in future. I don't plan on having this page connected to my mysql database at all.. the purpose of this dropdown is to link the user to the exact .php page which will then connect to the database of each question

Comment: @AaronC Since, you really want it that way, although, it's not really advisable and a good choice to do it that way, I already updated the answer. And also start getting rid of `pure javascript`, start learning `jQuery` for simpler and faster work. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Change the "submit" input to a button, add a "submit" function to couple with the button's onclick attribute.  The submit function I created just adds the subject and question that was selected into some "p" HTML elements that I created.  If you want the button to take the user to a separate url, maybe you can create a function with window.url = "".  Oh and I deleted the second script tag and added an event listener which waits for the html to fully load before executing.

```
function submit(){
  var subjects = document.getElementById("subjects").value
  var questions = document.getElementById("questions").value
  document.getElementById("ithquestion").innerHTML = questions
  document.getElementById("ithsubject").innerHTML = "Subject: " +  subjects



}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click',submit,false)
  resetForm(document.autoSelectForm);
})


</script>

<body>
  <form name="autoSelectForm" action="" method="post" >
    <select size="1" name="subjects" id = "subjects"        onchange="updateModels(this.form)">
    </select>
    <select size="1" name="questions" id = "questions">
    </select>
    <input type="button" value = "button" id = "button"/>
 </form>
 <p id = "ithsubject"></p>
 <p id = "ithquestion"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from but it isn't what I'm looking for. The question pages will have their own .php link. All i want is the Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 in each subject to have a href value of ... .html. This will make things a lot easier for me in future. I don't plan on having this page connected to my mysql database at all.. the purpose of this dropdown is to link the user to the exact .php page which will then connect to the database of each question